# Brick Wall separated from home and collapsed

Tags: electrical, walls, masonry, vinyl-siding

My home's brick wall has fallen down on 2 sides. I'm hoping to clear away the remaining bricks and install insulation and siding. I'm not sure how high of a base of bricks I should leave at the bottom. (so siding doesn't go down to the dirt). I'm also dealing with the outside electrical meter, not sure how I should handle that. Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks[image]

Comment: I'd say a good rule of thumb would be high enough to extend above your highest snow accumulation and drifting. Around my neck of the woods, that would be about 3 feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would want to repair the wall to the top of the window. It appears the window height is the same as the door. This would eliminate needing to call the power company to drop power to the house when you move the meter base and the need to re do the window and door casements. If you really want the brick gone, the bottom of the window would be the next best location to stop in my opinion.